# How to add MouseMotionListenter to a class that extends JLabel?

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, rmi, mouselistener

As the title says I am trying to add a `MouseMotionListener` to a class(`Magnet`) that I created which extends `JLabel`. The program is using RMI to communicate between client and server. The class that is extending the `JLabel` is the data that is being transferred. My issue is that when I add the `MouseMotionListener` in the client, the program doesn't register the movements. As I said the code I have below doesn't print anything even though it should. I don't get any warnings or error. I am really lost.

Here is the `Magnet` class

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private Font FONT = new Font("comic sans ms", Font.BOLD, 20);

private char letter;
private int x;
private int y;
private int id;

public Magnet(int x, int y, char letter, int id) {
    super();
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.id = id;
    this.letter = Character.toUpperCase(letter);
    setText(Character.toString(this.letter));
    setFont(FONT);
    setBounds(x, y, 25, 25);
}

public char getLetter() {
    return letter;
}

public int getID() {
    return id;
}

public int getX() {
    return x;
}

public int getY() {
    return y;
}

public void relocate(int x, int y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    setBounds(x, y, 25, 25);
}
```

The `client` class

```
setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 400, 400);
    setResizable(false);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setLayout(null);
    try {
        magnets = (MagnetInterface) Naming
                .lookup("//localhost:6667/MagnetServer");
        System.out.println("client: connected!");
        for (int i = 0; i < magnets.getSize(); i++) {
            magnets.getMagnet(0).addMouseMotionListener(
                            new MouseMotionListener() {

                @Override
                public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    System.out.println("test");
                }

                @Override
                public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    System.out.println("test");
                }
            });
            contentPane.add(tmp);
        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException | RemoteException | NotBoundException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        // e.printStackTrace();
    }
    setContentPane(contentPane);
```

Comment: The short answer is don't (as I understand the question).  UI components SHOULD NEVER be sent over the wire, they gain references to the local system which can't be serialized back to the server and cause at best `NotSerializableException`s and at worse `NullPointerException`s.  Besides, based on you code, I can't see where you add `magnets.getMagnet(0)` to the container anyway...

Comment: And I'd recommend including the imports and actual class declarations. Just so we know you're not accidentally doing anything silly like `import instant.fail.JLabel;` or something like  `class Magnet extends JLabel implements Cerealizable`

Comment: unrelated: a) all JSomethings are meant to be _used_ as-are (instead of extended) b) don't do any manual sizing/locating of components, that's the exclusive task of a suitable LayoutManager